# What does (?s).* mean in Apache mod_rewrite RewriteRule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I see the following statement in .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
```

What does this mean and why it is not just `(.*)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?s)` is to enable dot matching newlines as well so `.*` will match any character including newlines.

However there is no reason why `.*` won't work for you because space/newlines are decoded to their hex equivalent by browsers.